# Does $\limsup\limits_{k \in \mathbb N} \sqrt[k]{\lvert z_1^k + \dots + z_n^k \rvert} \ge 1$ for $\lvert z_1 \rvert = \dots = \lvert z_n \rvert = 1$?

Tags: complex-numbers

*This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4515679/prove-for-epsilon0-there-are-infinite-k-so-sqrtkz-1kz-2k-cdotsz).*

Suppose that $z_1, \dots, z_n$ are complex numbers of modulus equal to one: $\lvert z_1 \rvert = \dots = \lvert z_n \rvert = 1$. Do we have

$$\limsup\limits_{k \in \mathbb N} \sqrt[k]{\lvert z_1^k + \dots + z_n^k \rvert} \ge 1?$$

I started studying the case $n=2$. If $z_1 = e^{ia}, \, z_2 =e^{ib}$, we have

$$\lvert z_1^k + z_2^k \rvert = 2 \left\lvert \cos \frac{k(b-a)}{2} \right\rvert$$ and we can conclude positively using the structure of additive subgroups of the reals. However, I don't know how to tackle the general $n$ case.

Comment: All $z_i=1$, then $\sqrt[k]{n}$ has max $=n$ for k=1$.  fix question?

Comment: Why do I have to fix the question? I deal with the $\limsup$ here, not the $\sup$. See [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_inferior_and_limit_superior).

Comment: Note that the question asks for the minimal possible limsup and by the constraints we have that the limsup is at most $1$ since the expression is at most $n^{1/k}$ which goes to to $1$ as $k\to \infty$

Comment: @Conrad I do agree. We have to prove that the $\limsup$ is equal to $1$... which will prove that it is $\ge 1$!

Comment: This is an interesting question and i will think about; for only the sup the answer is yes (it is a classical problem which is not trivial btw as again the question asks about the minimal such on all n-uples on the unit circle, so for example for roots of unity most sums are zero and the largest is $n^{1/n}$ which is barely larger than $1$ for large $n$) and I think that the answer should be yes here too

Comment: I think that one can prove that out of any consecutive $n$ (or maybe $2n$ etc) sums $z_1^k+..z_n^k$ one is at least $1$ in absolute values with the roots of unity of order $n$ being the clear example that we need at least $n$ consecutive sums for such

Comment: Actually this is how we prove the result - we show that in the first $n$ sums, one is at least $1$ and then we apply this to $z^m$ for $m=2,3,. $; will put an answer later when home

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $s_k=z_1^k+..z_n^k$. We will show that there is at least one $q=1,2,..,n$ for which $|s_q|\ge 1$ and that will be enough since for every $m \ge 1$ we can apply this to $z_j^m$ and get a sequence $|s_{q_m}|\ge 1$.

Let $P(z)=(z-z_1)...(z-z_n)=z^n+a_1z^{n-1}+..a_n$ the monic polynomial with roots $z_j$ and note that $|a_n|=1$ by the hypothesis $|z_j|=1$ so $|a_q|$ the maximum of the $|a_j|$ is at least $1$

By the Newton relations we have that $$ja_j-a_{j-1}s_1+a_{j-2}s_2...\pm s_j=0, k=1,..,n$$

Applying for $j=q$ and using the triangle inequality (and the fact that $1, |a_j|\le |a_q|$) we have that $$q|a_q| \le (1+|a_1|+..|a_{q-1}|)\max_{1,.,q} |s_j| \le q|a_q|  \max_{1,..,q}|s_j|$$ and we are done!

Comment: Nice usage of Newton’s identities and of $a_n$! Thanks.

Comment: Happy to be of help